# Combo Box Filter Based on Value in Hidden Form

Tags: ms-access-2010

After a successful logon information about the user is held in a always open but hidden form.

Within the program there are various dropdowns that I want to filter based on 'txt_security' from the hidden form.

Row Source Example

```
SELECT tbl_master_ship.master_ship_id, tbl_master_ship.admin_only
FROM tbl_master_ship;
```

Example of data is there are 5 total ships, only one is admin_only.  If txt_security = 1 then show all 5 ships else hide the one record marked admin_only.

I tried this but it only shows the one record if txt_security = 1.

```
WHERE (((tbl_master_ship.admin_only)=IIf([forms]![frm_global_variables]![txt_security]=0,True,False)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the easiest way:

```
WHERE [Forms]![frm_global_variables]![txt_security] = 1
   OR tbl_master_ship.admin_only = 0
```

Only if `[txt_security] <> 1` AND `admin_only = True` will the record not be shown.

Comment: As usual I thought it would more complicated.